# from z-score to p-value - how to do this for this hypothesis-set?

Tags: p-value

I know that if

```
H0: μ = 1.35
```

then if
`H1: μ != 1.35` means p-value is 2P(Z ≥ |z|)

else if

```
H1: μ > 1.35 then P(Z ≥ z) and H1: μ < 1.35 means p-value is P(Z ≤ z)
```

However, I am stumped about how to do it with following sets of hypothesis.

```
H0: μ ≥ 1.35 
H1: μ < 1.35
```

### p-value=??

```
H0: μ ≤ 1.35 
H1: μ > 1.35
```

p-value=??

Comment: You might benefit from exploring [the highest-voted questions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes&pageSize=50) related to the [tag:p-value] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the p-value is not z or 2*z. P values range from 0 to 1, z scores can be any real number. But perhaps you mean how to look up p in a z table? I am not sure.

Second, if the variable that $\mu$ is the average of is continuous, then $p(\mu \le 1.35) = p(\mu \lt 1.35)$ because the probability of any exact value of $\mu$ is infinitesimal.

Comment: Yes, I agree p-value is not z or 2*z. Just a typo. Please see my edit above. Now, how to compute p-value when H0 is not a fixed constant but a range of values? (inequality sign)

Comment: You already wrote the solution to that in your problem, in the second box

Comment: Are you talking about H1: μ > 1.35 then P(Z ≥ z) and H1: μ < 1.35 means p-value is P(Z ≤ z)? but this assumes H0 = 1.35. The question I'm asking has H0 with inequality too! Are you saying it doesn't matter? (Both H0 and H1 have inequalities in my question!)

Comment: No it doesn't assume $\mu = 1.35$, it assumes it is either <= 1.35 or >= 1.35. An H0 that $\mu = 1.35$ could be rejected 100% of the time with no error. $PR(\mu = 1.35) = 0$