# How can I find a Z score from a p-value?

Tags: p-value, z-statistic

How can I find a *Z* score from a p-value? I know how to look up the p-value from a *Z* score using a Normal distribution table, but I don't know how to calculate it.
For example, a question says the alpha equals 5 percent. From this, I see in my handout that the *Z* score is calculated to be 1.65.  How do I determine this?
Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be related to this question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/from-z-score-to-p-value-how-to-do-this-for-this-hypothesis-set

Comment: How is your table organized? There are at least 3 or 4 different setups.

Comment: You can use the same table as for finding p-values, but you look for the probability value in the *body* of the table, and then read off the Z that gives that value. If you can convey adequately what is tabulated in your tables and how it's organized (there are images of [tables on line](https://www.google.com/search?q=normal+distribution+tables&tbm=isch), if you find one that's effectively identical to yours, a link would suffice), then I'll try to come back with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically the tables for $p$-values for the $Z$ distribution are arranged with values of $Z$ defining the row and column headers, and the body of the table consists of $p$-values.

If you are given a $Z$ value, you go to the corresponding row and column to look in the table. However, you can do the reverse of this, right? Given $p$ (or $\alpha$), you can find this value in the table and then look at the row and column headers to get $Z$.

Ta da!

Answer (score 17):

Actually, $z_{.95}=1.6\underline{\mathbf{4}}$; your handout is **LIES!** (I'm being facetiously hyperbolic because the author seems to have rounded up somewhat improperly. It's not really a big deal.)

In [r](/questions/tagged/r), the `qnorm` function converts probabilities (akin to [distribution quantiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)) to *z*-scores. Thus:

```
> qnorm(.95)
[1] 1.644854
```

The documation for `qnorm` lists the following reference for the algorithm, in case you want it. If you prefer not to use R, [John Walker's calculator](http://www.fourmilab.ch/rpkp/experiments/analysis/zCalc.html) works through JavaScript-enabled web browsers. He also offers some equations that could be rearranged to do this by hand. You may also wish to check "[How to deal with Z-score greater than 3?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/97745/32036)"

---

<sup>**Reference**

Wichura, M. J. (1988) Algorithm AS 241: The percentage points of the normal distribution. *Applied Statistics, 37*, 477–484.</sup>

Comment: It perhaps makes sense to round up (or more generally away from the median) if you want your resulting significance levels to be conservative.